# Передача исключений выше в программу

Tags: php, sql-server, try-catch

Добрый день!
Используется связка php+mssql.
В базе есть процедура с блоком try catch

```
Begin try
...
Throw 50000, 'test throw', 1
...
End try
Begin catch
  Select error_message();
Throw;
End catch
```

При прогоне в мсстудио все корректно: транзакции прекращаются, выводится текст ошибки.
При прогоне в php тоже транзакции прекращаются, но не генерируется исключение и я не могу определить завершилась ли процедура корректно или с исключением. Как исправить или как отлавливать?

Answer (score 0):

Исключения в БД MSSQL и исключения в PHP - это две абсолютно разные сущности, не связанные друг с другом никак от слова совсем.

Для обработки ошибок возникших в БД используйте функции обработки ошибок используемого вами драйвера. Если это, например, PDO, то [PDOStatement::errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.errorinfo.php), если SQLSRV, то [sqlsrv_errors](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sqlsrv-errors.php)

Для того, чтобы MSSQL вернул ошибку в драйвер, используемый PHP, в блоке `catch` вместо `Throw;` используйте `RAISEERROR(...)`

Comment: Да, это понятно. Я и не жду пхп-шного исключения. Жду именно в sqlsrv_errors, там ничего нет

Comment: @АлексейМайборода а что там появится, если у вас пустой `Throw;` Задайте ему код, описание наконец

Comment: Не помогает - пробовал.

Comment: @АлексейМайборода может RAISEERROR?

Comment: Да, raiseerror сработал! Спасибо!